# yarn run ios runs the simulator but the app icon is not displayed

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, yarnpkg, create-react-native-app

I have just started to learn ReactNative because I want to build mobile apps. For that purpose I use my Mac with installed yarn, create-react-native-app and Xcode.

When I run the command:

```
sudo yarn run ios
```

the build is successful. No error displayed and the simulator opens but the screen does not display the icon of the app (my project).

[image]

If I run the android simulator with Android Studio and the command:

```
sudo yarn run android
```

the Android simulator runs and displayed the app.

What might be the issue with the iOS simulator? Please help!

## =============

MORE DETAILS:

Here are the commands I use to set up the project:

```
brew install yarn --without-node
mkdir projectX
cd projectX
sudo yarn global add create-react-native-app
sudo create-react-native .
```

NodeJS, JDK, JSK are initially installed. After entering these commands I had to upgrade the versions of react and react-native with:

```
sudo yarn remove react-native
sudo yarn add react-native
sudo yarn remove react
sudo yarn add react
```

After that:

```
sudo yarn run eject
adb
sudo yarn run ios
```

Comment: Did you run `yarn run ios` using `sudo`?

Comment: Yes. I used sudo.

Comment: Well, then run the following: `sudo chown -R yourUserName ~/.babel.json &&
sudo chown -R yourUserName ~/.expo`, and try it again without `sudo`.

Comment: I tried it and here is what I got: chown: /Users/USERNAME/.babel.json: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned here in the Github issues: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/422, you most likely used `sudo` while running the app on the iOS simulator. This operation made `root` the owner of some files.

Before running the iOS app, try the following command:

`sudo chown -R yourUserName ~/react_native_projects`, note that `react_native_projects` should be the folder of your project.

Which should fix the ownership of your project files, and fix the emulator issue. Also take a look at the Github issue page for more helpful commands.

Comment: I did the following:

`sudo chown -R admin ~/Documents/SoftwareDevelopment/_Education/ReactNative/projectX/`
`sudo yarn run ios`

The simulator and the metro bundler opened. The simulator does not show the app icon but also the Metro Bundler is stuck to this message "Loading dependency graph, done." and it does not continue...which wasn't the case before that.

Comment: Ok, it worked now! Thank you for the help. Here is what I did step by step:
`sudo chown -R myUserName ~/react_native_project` then I restarted the Mac (following the comments from the GitHub link) and in the terminal I typed `yarn run ios`. Notice that I didn't use `sudo`! If you try to run it with `sudo` it won't work. Thanks mate! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Giovanni Terlingen I fixed it. Here are the steps I followed:

First I changed the ownership of the directory which contains my project to the user to be owned by my user.

```
sudo chown -R myUserName ~/react_native_project
```

Then I restarted my Mac (following the comments from the GitHub link provided by Giovanni) and in the terminal I typed:

```
yarn run ios
```

Notice that I didn't use `sudo`! If you try to run it with `sudo` it won't work.